# Vue 2: global event listener receives only once

Tags: javascript, vue.js

To sumarize what I'm trying to achieve, I'm creating a calendar, where each day is a component instance, and inside each day there can be zero to multiple instances of a smaller component, named Task, kind of like this.

```
<Root>
  <CalendarDay>
    <Task></Task>
    <Task></Task>
    ...
  </CalendarDay>
  <CalendarDay></CalendarDay>
  ...
</Root>
```

The number of smaller components to draw is dependent of a data array placed on the root component, which is expected to change multiple times via API calls.

The flow I had in mind is, first draw the CalendarDay components, then make an API call to obtain the Tasks that must be drawn on all days drawn, and finally fire a global event so that each CalendarDay retrieves the Tasks assigned to it. To achieve it, I added an eventBus to Vue following the steps of an answer of another question here, which I can't find, but basically is setting an extra property on the Vue prototype.

```
Vue.prototype.$eventHub = new Vue(); // Global event bus
```

Everything is set up, and on the first execution the API retrieves the Tasks, a global event is fired, and all CalendarDay components retrieve and draw the Tasks; but when a second global event is fired, the listeners either don't receive anything or they are not responding.

Here are the root and components

```
// ROOT Component
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#appVue',
    data: function() {
        return {
          ...
          tasks: [],
          calendar_days: []   // Each element in this array is an object with 2 properties: numday and weekday
          ...
        }
    },
    methods: {
        db_get_tasks_month: function(){
            REMOTE_WS.get(`<API route>`)
                .then(response => {
                    this.tasks= response.data.tasks;
                    
                    this.$eventHub.$emit('sort-tasks-in-days');
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error('err');
                });
        },
        ...
     }
})

// CalendarDay Component
Vue.component('calendar-day', {
    props: {'day': Object}, //{numday, weekday}
    data: function(){
        return {
            tasks: []
        };
    },
    methods: {
        sortTasksInDays: function(){
            this.tasks= this.$root.$data.tasks.filter(t => {
                return t.hasOwnProperty("data_ts") && new Date(t.data_ts).getDate() === this.day.numday;
            });
        }
    },
    created: function(){ this.$eventHub.$on('sort-tasks-in-days', this.sortTasksInDays) },
    beforeDestroy: function(){ this.$eventHub.$off('sort-tasks-in-days'); }
});
```

Could someone point out what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

EDIT: To add a bit more info, I checked if the global event is even firing, and using the Vue plugin on Chrome I can confirm that it is indeed firing, so what I'm missing must be on the listeners.
EDIT 2: Adding the property in ROOT where the calendar days are stored to display on a v-for

SOLVED: as Niels pointed out, passing the Tasks array as a prop was a solution. For future reference, the changes made to make it work are as follows:

```
// ROOT Component: The calendar_days data in root is this
data: function() {
        return {
          ...
          tasks: [],
          calendar_days: []   // Each element in this array is an object with 3 properties: numday, weekday and tasks
          ...
        }
    },
methods: {
    // The method db_get_tasks_month no longer does the global event emit
    // The tasks are passed as a prop to each component

}

// CalendarDay Component
Vue.component('calendar-day', {
    props: {
        numday: { type: Number, default: 0},
        weekday: { type: Number, default: 0},
        tasks: { type: Array, default: []}
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I was wondering why you are using a global event bus for this. This issue seems rather trivial and can be solved using component properties. This would create a more readable structure.

As it appears, every calendar day needs an array of Tasks. This can be defined in the 'props'-property of your CalendarDay. Your CalendarDay holds too much inforamtion now. It is using root-information whch is later on filtered out.
There's plenty of ways to get the data in the format you need but I think mapping whenever you fetch the data is the easiest. You map the response.data to the format:

```
days: {
  '1': [],
  '2': ['task A', 'Task B'],
  ...
}
```

Then it is a matter of looping over this object in your root-template and passing the tasks along as props (these are reactive).

```
<calendar-day v-for="(tasks, day) in days" :key="day" :tasks="tasks" :day-number="day"></calendar-day>
```

Comment: Just realized I forgot to add the array where the calendar days are stored in root, I'm updating the question to add it. Would this work if, instead of having an array, each element in the 'days' property was an Object?

Comment: To answer my own question, yes it does kinda accept Object, I'll update the question to post the solution for whoever comes across this situation